# how to read chinese from pdf in ios correctly

Tags: ios, pdf, localization

here is what I have done, but it appears disorderly. Thanks in advance.

1.use **CGPDFStringCopyTextString** to get the text from the pdf

2.encode the NSString to char*

```
NSStringEncoding enc = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingGB_18030_2000);
const char *char_content = [self.currentData cStringUsingEncoding:enc];
```

Below is how I get the currentData:

```
void arrayCallback(CGPDFScannerRef inScanner, void *userInfo)
{
  BIDViewController *pp = (__bridge BIDViewController*)userInfo;
  CGPDFArrayRef array;
  bool success = CGPDFScannerPopArray(inScanner, &array);
  for(size_t n = 0; n < CGPDFArrayGetCount(array); n += 1)
  {
      if(n >= CGPDFArrayGetCount(array))
          continue;
      CGPDFStringRef string;
      success = CGPDFArrayGetString(array, n, &string);
      if(success)
      {
          NSString *data = (__bridge NSString *)CGPDFStringCopyTextString(string);
          [pp.currentData appendFormat:@"%@", data];
      }
  }
}
 - (IBAction)press:(id)sender {
    table = CGPDFOperatorTableCreate();
    CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(table, "TJ", arrayCallback);
    CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback(table, "Tj", stringCallback);
    self.currentData = [NSMutableString string];
    CGPDFContentStreamRef contentStream = CGPDFContentStreamCreateWithPage(pagerf);
    CGPDFScannerRef scanner = CGPDFScannerCreate(contentStream, table, (__bridge void *)(self));
    bool ret = CGPDFScannerScan(scanner);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *disorderly*? And have you checked whether the output of `CGPDFStringCopyTextString` indeed is *GB_18030_2000* encoded?

Comment: I mean that characters changed to be irrecognizable because different coder or other reasons. And how to get the encoding type of CGPDFStringCopyTextString?Thx

Comment: I want to encode the CGPDFStringCopyTextString with GB_18030_2000, it should show the chinese correctly, but it doesn't works....

Comment: The problem may already be before your GB_18030_2000 encoding is used, cf. my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the Mac Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPDFString/Reference/reference.html) 
`CGPDFStringCopyTextString` *returns a CFString object that represents a PDF string as a text string*. The PDF string is given as a `CGPDFString` which is *a series of bytes—unsigned integer values in the range 0 to 255*; thus, this method already decodes the bytes according to some character encoding.

It is given none explicitly, so it assumes one encoding type, most likely the **PDFDocEncoding** or the **UTF-16BE** Unicode character encoding scheme which are the two encodings that may be used to represent text strings in a PDF document *outside the document’s content streams*, cf. section 7.9.2.2 *Text String Type* and Table D.1, Annex D in [the PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

Now you have not told us from where you received your `CGPDFString`. I assume, though, that you received it from *inside one of the document’s content streams*. Text strings there, on the other hand, can be encoded with any imaginable encoding. The encoding used is given by the embedded data of the font the string is to be displayed with.

For more information on this you may want to read [CGPDFScannerPopString returning strange result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998640/cgpdfscannerpopstring-returning-strange-result/13998859) and have a look at [PDFKitten](https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten).

Comment: I do not understand entirely. Can you explain more? I have add more code in question. I have tried PDFKitten's example, but when I search Chinese, it seems not work well. Many thanks.

Comment: Ok, your code addition confirm my assumptions, your CGPDFStrings are from the contents of pages of your PDF. Thus, their encoding is given by their fonts, not a single fixed encoding. CGPDFStringCopyTextString assumes a fixed encoding, though. Thus, unless you are lucky, that method returns gibberish. Please have a look at the references i gave.

Comment: PDFKitten unfortunately is not very good, yet, but it is way better than just using CGPDFStringCopyTextString and assuming it is right.