# PDFKitten - handling accents and special characters

Tags: ios, search, pdf, highlighting

I'm using [PDFKitten](https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten) for searching in pdf files in my app. It isn't able to find words that contains accents (also other special characters). Also when a row contains some of these character, the highlighted rectangle of the searched word is shifted and so incorrect.
I've read [PDFKitten is highlighting on wrong position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914479/pdfkitten-is-highlighting-on-wrong-position) but the workaround https://github.com/KurtCode/PDFKitten/issues/48#issuecomment-9912313 isn't working for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The workaround mentioned in the comments to that stackoverflow answer only works for special cases. If you implemented the enhancement proposed in the answer itself, you might get what you need.

Comment: thank you, I will try to implement that enhancement and update my question, did you already try that solution? thanks

Comment: As mentioned in that answer, I'm programming mainly in Java and can merely read objective c. Thus, no, I have not tried implementing that but merely analyzed the existing code.

Comment: I', trying to develop your idea, can you explain what would you do in didScanCharacter if you move its logic into didScanCID? thanks for your help